# In Excel, position group icon above the group

Tags: excel, grouping

In Excel, when you create a group and collapse it, the "+" expand or "-" collapse button appears next to the row that follows the collapsing group. This corresponds to the expectation that, for example, this row is a subtotal of the (hidden) detail rows above.

I have a situation where the collapsed rows provide details pertaining to the *preceding* row. So I want the +/- button next to the preceding row, not the following row.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a macro to create grouping then try this.

```
.SummaryRow = xlAbove
```

full code.

```
With ActiveSheet.Outline
    .AutomaticStyles = False
    .SummaryRow = xlAbove
    .SummaryColumn = xlRight
End With
```

If you're doing it manually then click on the tiny little expand arrow in the bottom corner of the grouping section on the menu and then untick the ‘Summary rows below detail’ in the dialouge box that opens.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: To be honest, I didn't have much hope there would be an answer to this.  Stackoverflow (and Gordon) awesome once again!

Comment: I had to answer because it annoys me that Excel's default setting is "backwards".  I knew I wasn't the only one who thought that.

Comment: I can see applications for either ordering. The annoyance is that the behavior does a very distinctive thing (associates a group with a row that's not part of the selected group), so it might be distinctly the right choice, or distinctly wrong -- yet the option to change the ordering was not readily apparent to me. Further, it's difficult to determine what to call the feature in order to google for it. FWIW, I do indeed create the (many) groups by VBA, and while the effect of expandable/collapsible is great for the end users, the blemish of having the +/- in the wrong place was galling.